# Quering a variety of characters in a search condition regardless of order within the string

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        `Magic The Gathering`
    WHERE
        `set` =  'Magic 2013'
    ORDER BY
        (CASE
            WHEN `cost` LIKE '%B%' THEN 1
            WHEN `cost` LIKE '%R%' THEN 2
            WHEN `cost` LIKE '%G%' THEN 3
            WHEN `cost` LIKE '%W%' THEN 4
            WHEN `cost` LIKE '%U%' THEN 5
            WHEN `cost` LIKE '%B%U%' THEN 6
            ELSE 7
        END),
        FIELD (`rarity`, 'Mythic', 'Rare', 'Uncommon', 'Common', 'Land') ASC,
        (CASE
            WHEN `type` LIKE '%Planeswalker%' THEN 1
            WHEN `type` LIKE '%Creature%' THEN 2
            WHEN `type` LIKE '%Instant%' THEN 3
            WHEN `type` LIKE '%Sorcery%' THEN 4
            WHEN `type` LIKE '%Enchantment%' THEN 5
            WHEN `type` LIKE '%Artifact%' THEN 6
            WHEN `type` LIKE '%Land%' THEN 7
        END)
    LIMIT
        500
```

If you look at the line...

```
WHEN `cost` LIKE '%B%U%' THEN 6
```

How can I make it so it supports both

```
WHEN `cost` LIKE '%B%U%' THEN 6
```

and

```
WHEN `cost` LIKE '%U%B%' THEN 6
```

Notice the U is now in front of B. Or even a variety such as...

```
WHEN `cost` LIKE '%B%U%G%R%' THEN 6
```

Basically if any of those characters are in the string regardless of order, it should work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this with separate likes:

```
when cost like '%b%' and cost like '%u%' then ...
```

You can also use regular expressions, particularly if the patterns get more complicated:

```
when cost regexp '.*[bu].*' then ...
```